# Merge rows in pandas based on a common data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a CSV file where the data of one ID is in many rows. I want to merge all the data of one ID in one row by increasing the number of columns.

```
Id        X         Y  
ABC      56        23  
ABC      77        74  
XYX      11        51
```

to

```
Id        X        Y         X         Y  
ABC      56       23        77        74 
XYX      11       51
```

How to do it?

Comment: Hey! Sharing some data and expected output helps a lot. If you also show some effort (that you tried to solve the problem) that is great!

Comment: I have added the expected output. I tried join() but couldn't find a way to get this output.

Comment: Do you really want columns with same names?

Comment: @MohitMotwani That is the format that I am supposed to submit my work in. Although having different columns names won't do much harm.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: @MeHdi Not homework but something like practice questions

Comment: I don't get your question, yo cannot have several columns with the same name! as far as I know.

Comment: @MeHdi is it possible to do the same with different column names?